# Implementing Diffie-Hellman in python. Shared secret keys aren't getting matched

Tags: python, cryptography, sympy, diffie-hellman

hope everything is well. I am trying to implement the Diffie_Hellman in Python. I read that for better security, it is recommended that the prime 
should be at least 2048 bits long, and  should generate a subgroup of size at least 2^128. I wrote the code for managing this, but sadly the shared secret keys I am getting aren't matched for both the sender and the receiver.

Here's the code:

```
import random
import secrets
from sympy import isprime

def get_large_prime(bit_length):
    while True:
        prime_candidate = random.getrandbits(bit_length)
        # Ensure the number has the correct bit length and is odd
        prime_candidate |= (1 << bit_length - 1) | 1
        if isprime(prime_candidate):
            return prime_candidate

def find_generator(p):
    """Find a generator for the multiplicative group modulo p."""
    # Candidates for g that often generate large subgroups
    candidate_values = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37]

    for g_candidate in candidate_values:
        if pow(g_candidate, (p-1)//2, p) != 1 and pow(g_candidate, (p-1)//3, p) != 1:
            return g_candidate

    # If none of the candidates work, use a generic search
    g = 2
    subgroup_size = 1
    while subgroup_size < 2**128:
        g += 1
        subgroup_size = pow(g, (p-1)//2, p)
    return g

def generate_private_key():
    """Generate a private key."""
    return secrets.randbelow(2**128 - 1) + 2  # Use secrets module for more secure random number generation

def calculate_public_key(generator, private_key, prime):
    """Calculate the public key."""
    return pow(generator, private_key, prime)

def calculate_shared_secret(public_key, private_key, prime):
    """Calculate the shared secret key."""
    return pow(public_key, private_key, prime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bit_length = 2048

    # Generate a large prime number and a generator for the sender
    sender_prime = get_large_prime(bit_length)
    sender_generator = find_generator(sender_prime)
    sender_private_key = generate_private_key()
    sender_public_key = calculate_public_key(sender_generator, sender_private_key, sender_prime)

    # Generate a large prime number and a generator for the receiver
    receiver_prime = get_large_prime(bit_length)
    receiver_generator = find_generator(receiver_prime)
    receiver_private_key = generate_private_key()
    receiver_public_key = calculate_public_key(receiver_generator, receiver_private_key, receiver_prime)

    # Exchange public keys
    sender_shared_secret = calculate_shared_secret(receiver_public_key, sender_private_key, sender_prime)
    receiver_shared_secret = calculate_shared_secret(sender_public_key, receiver_private_key, receiver_prime)

    print(f"Sender's {bit_length}-bit prime is:\n{sender_prime}")
    print(f"Sender's generator for the group is:\n{sender_generator}")
    print(f"Sender's private key is:\n{sender_private_key}")
    print(f"Sender's public key is:\n{sender_public_key}")
    print(f"Sender's shared secret key is:\n{sender_shared_secret}\n")

    print(f"Receiver's {bit_length}-bit prime is:\n{receiver_prime}")
    print(f"Receiver's generator for the group is:\n{receiver_generator}")
    print(f"Receiver's private key is:\n{receiver_private_key}")
    print(f"Receiver's public key is:\n{receiver_public_key}")
    print(f"Receiver's shared secret key is:\n{receiver_shared_secret}")
```

Here's the output I am getting:

```
Sender's 2048-bit prime is:
32221686490172290560951951774790258460511868236561699121155218960182686672268366824979336043526909174261098452725855386505897506209694348499911039436641080845094359385613013005904354882991155555969461828748177396576617140218457422066028808302301029566190549321140606549375380639043920388602437077015364721949831852984663199820354046717364480597620765436189605761901460431220869026471178146105794252789600089360200963485371408324910599189616457023443860236211419804657495974811016700435647800335341960496809239766311614421810504039975719680312731263581495083550561163971336872957582148769583012551294922894280883597199
Sender's generator for the group is:
3
Sender's private key is:
124161865596736545475872180257413276158
Sender's public key is:
26348168443085206721793219397353997644864553194627246314438201078613883234326432362112043265586150398428558442614339782536235939107904805860514462539057036353021254195836396753058409136899810717127251401312050493274455914758258564495637537084967894708233008864374337557390931606322869822375849936953726735257437496401870481578582511990596335291540316831462649745928196169608961005401659039537266406396219939256826276138995553394692852418041325196981953013991477020980939376361371583173665981303731359304915087735452468595135872474587202250785307306219478547626467495218651932601220067722700387594194835809984844369998
Sender's shared secret key is:
21093143999990752148312413695648824570758887028632314884561865933843735557602491613563078224487331124950094148941447141936256178898529507708765186087292255627512603328719230184097191287594103707538060227810115464339501434728573471082926548024613545180073530225371334786540519082473606356594200745787229896149191402645526263533516301226185349459059775161425383207553676936145267269980734152647845935509878954783230323387631184636543935583627083720559038953531384546311907944394596271999397209274634834850455094198618873541064103892843410931947535296422375053157899457506295346870758919984577340783966014807976149679696

Receiver's 2048-bit prime is:
28976802397353577319062926658877744178503880496815037762628896414753669717663397674152831685113987447038010888674566279621668078832785981730653145652257955384436505204829089716469012016395533554875106781294724763867476051454833198933742421257681393757058316514804910595872009122120896625781392830718028992520516457032443260758033082444235011551763566523528284020737676316315015458821032000655995744718617184214612580369801281243260565786838425247444037623738001452768035685926703086900893696348870553160697781709208153551428931225450904418180607413359613662485532116487800866582022088783037276958617482856698819022911
Receiver's generator for the group is:
11
Receiver's private key is:
156875722145573500478673548695322470331
Receiver's public key is:
5305990774705988595439743046083747673154230769427043607543697107051407404317801002244794588375639295690270480209042376133050302805593217841630760988261264248764102958156115497112768460231324786872032512239501441267597449065705550623115963101625881596190069280767257964743493730559432023214264797869451256868226806226735996064615498686671690337103447954583357906712952627965331629510882805836803177520102499132076649782487058481798962704432767956705897830712176145178743795350120306536358871487880475118557393686645197580694818638462401327844850588347528039763660404253199654188986504787177321430068606278286398687930
Receiver's shared secret key is:
23343431484208419386989305551698199582042408816049631058695451189766926551931740146922786176847907465438728216138879286523678235439179674405276027162264146468256738940719599743470261832690758822520665856060864810227485370267231851129160342119467133368900972545543620233989213405232047072953095569389341643624743854289585338694316799049995269895267333345022123253040715008290321357811034128341902885807243347943393598257341584499155660461822262188727630038361285953193985905333739345220269931167181413507248982944656912023078919598028538088650009124546705320123558799128727428993709018214620778848094810961084502325198
```

**UPDATE**

Code:

```
import random
from sympy import isprime, factorint
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime

def get_large_prime(bit_length):
    return getPrime(bit_length)

def find_generator(p):
    factors = factorint(p-1)
    
    for g_candidate in range(2, p):
        is_generator = True
        for factor in factors:
            if pow(g_candidate, (p-1)//factor, p) == 1:
                is_generator = False
                break
        if is_generator:
            return g_candidate

def generate_private_key():
    return random.randint(2, 2**128)

def calculate_public_key(generator, private_key, prime):
    return pow(generator, private_key, prime)

def calculate_shared_secret(public_key, private_key, prime):
    return pow(public_key, private_key, prime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bit_length = 2048

    # Generate a large prime number and a generator for the sender and receiver
    shared_prime = get_large_prime(bit_length)
    shared_generator = find_generator(shared_prime)

    # Generate private keys for the sender and receiver
    sender_private_key = generate_private_key()
    receiver_private_key = generate_private_key()

    # Calculate public keys for the sender and receiver
    sender_public_key = calculate_public_key(shared_generator, sender_private_key, shared_prime)
    receiver_public_key = calculate_public_key(shared_generator, receiver_private_key, shared_prime)

    # Exchange public keys
    sender_shared_secret = calculate_shared_secret(receiver_public_key, sender_private_key, shared_prime)
    receiver_shared_secret = calculate_shared_secret(sender_public_key, receiver_private_key, shared_prime)

    print(f"Shared {bit_length}-bit prime is:\n{shared_prime}")
    print(f"Shared generator for the group is:\n{shared_generator}")

    print("\nSender:")
    print(f"Sender's private key is:\n{sender_private_key}")
    print(f"Sender's public key is:\n{sender_public_key}")
    print(f"Sender's shared secret key is:\n{sender_shared_secret}\n")

    print("Receiver:")
    print(f"Receiver's private key is:\n{receiver_private_key}")
    print(f"Receiver's public key is:\n{receiver_public_key}")
    print(f"Receiver's shared secret key is:\n{receiver_shared_secret}")
```

Output:

```
Shared 2048-bit prime is:
16899290410341716572396500639338421918149765091468487135220652650709698911193474418757406023792601235504593878017964912783586003082034352840947305743950452599705299202335386369810159979082746314315701438407953338440509989481731906394354034704328838084743695911063023400991205526771239045329737675477412673709532659702298110107324090648432821384418970091466270866390118559321732710525699516133920440924736113044514138389852039672800194917535290618917463904117557520264288878064935863360490331640313062243810766671027510945317192096289175427825554353432632036768954025754878652362062305174188873074676394003010853504531
Shared generator for the group is:
2

Sender:
Sender's private key is:
161236650027313735934797782458980097398
Sender's public key is:
7971856757910394108922951410380447364751224558431116344441240025008569568809578524371567650785584853079836013679904085031776514201771382683345840423901705275216751735538909624879047067384474658373938133163700360559276684851018138743535759873536337241654548309524375709506429606126603819710965399401479731940571729124820672836514181922058522610152828493722469528658078715989099251500879802514159818924395688701213151845823566933238007179034142982348268515118507531553386711128180272972335434628463183195287678596482580666652310441361390378828579820453242040992676533511891926767445547313654703605917948041390714911738
Sender's shared secret key is:
4345776665398179044799343721610980787234798487209135354173209491503712546309831652467888319914600859151869628075752433831384942612296891020237206597016560093610165132824430663846221885370221726683912176207896930392347135491714515491502215055785783913364118977827150375472559759151326509391118971817492945430393447337409713925211361397155027022435172253101940752174050568345683174716632785242845755562871066257465827923952933964572371464137817573915046776839798708468670105955214093470129758964911913766734059396662435752842332892030623883795286515827047795450442541860407024929084645119029553347831392682185704360207

Receiver:
Receiver's private key is:
330891456741035173262850158429026798965
Receiver's public key is:
603771668959628491125782128408918656668054975098319487215159658303523807710722236309207304669011604621884194238410396789930817346050513381354992053849834433681672418756998384534593116919848150433507763837487028783135720917510857636536028171370292083444403804042677648138710459990899452095049691411319737270990685588885128903469732586553665334441577860913932724687424243073895842017528350812520453970607109310943508555496637142805726586144585871823727263378505021224591713513712970228332329505202435437737761446777124217039609797611061418578596852296974578391240074183641564334727134093054419432496087964448288537612
Receiver's shared secret key is:
4345776665398179044799343721610980787234798487209135354173209491503712546309831652467888319914600859151869628075752433831384942612296891020237206597016560093610165132824430663846221885370221726683912176207896930392347135491714515491502215055785783913364118977827150375472559759151326509391118971817492945430393447337409713925211361397155027022435172253101940752174050568345683174716632785242845755562871066257465827923952933964572371464137817573915046776839798708468670105955214093470129758964911913766734059396662435752842332892030623883795286515827047795450442541860407024929084645119029553347831392682185704360207
```

Now, I am getting same shared secret key.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: This is not how vanilla Diffie Hellman works. For one thing, both the sender and receiver must use the same prime and the same base, or generator as you have termed it. For another, your computation of the generator seems far from correct. You have to know the factorization of p-1 to determine the order of a given element. If, however, p-1=2p' where p' is also prime, then this computation is greatly simplified.

Comment: _p_ and _g_ are the parameters of the algorithm; they need to be the same on both sides or the algorithm won't work. Usually we use *named* parameters nowaways, e.g. those in [RFC 3526](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526.html#section-3)

Comment: Unless this is for a homework problem, you should *never* implement your own Diffie Hellman.  It is virtually guaranteed that your implementation will have a security hole of some sort.  Only use algorithms and implementations that have been vetted by experts.

Comment: Thank you all. I made some modifications as per your suggestions. I am putting it there, please let me know if it works. 
@PresidentJamesK.Polk